# App crashing on Handsets but running smooth on emulators

Tags: android

Well i was very much impressed with a gif so i decided to split it into png format and use inside my application splash screen but after splitting i got a bunch of 272 images which when i added into my app runs fine on emulator then after finishing up when i launched it into my handset it crashes, so i decided to installed it on a handset with a higher ram then also nothing happened and it again crashes whats the problem here?

```
package com.smp.ravirathore.animation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView img;
    Button btn;
    TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable;
    AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public void action(View btn){

        animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anim_list);
        img.setImageDrawable(animationDrawable);
        animationDrawable.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(animationDrawable.isRunning()){
            animationDrawable.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is the enim.xml file...well i used python for this long code :P

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a1n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a2n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a3n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a4n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a5n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a6n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a7n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a8n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a9n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a10n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a11n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a12n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a13n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a14n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a15n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a16n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a17n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a18n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a19n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a20n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a21n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a22n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a23n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a24n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a25n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a26n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a27n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a28n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a29n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a30n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a31n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a32n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a33n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a34n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a35n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a36n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a37n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a38n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a39n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a40n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a41n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a42n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a43n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a44n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a45n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a46n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a47n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a48n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a49n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a50n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a51n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a52n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a53n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a54n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a55n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a56n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a57n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a58n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a59n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a60n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a61n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a62n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a63n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a64n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a65n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a66n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a67n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a68n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a69n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a70n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a71n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a72n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a73n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a74n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a75n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a76n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a77n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a78n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a79n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a80n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a81n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a82n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a83n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a84n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a85n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a86n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a87n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a88n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a89n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a90n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a91n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a92n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a93n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a94n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a95n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a96n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a97n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a98n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a99n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a100n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a101n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a102n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a103n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a104n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a105n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a106n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a107n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a108n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a109n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a150n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a111n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a112n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a113n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a114n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a115n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a116n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a117n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a118n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a119n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a120n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a121n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a122n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a123n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a124n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a125n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a126n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a127n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a128n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a129n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a130n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a131n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a132n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a133n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a134n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a135n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a136n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a137n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a138n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a139n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a140n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a141n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a142n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a143n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a144n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a145n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a146n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a147n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a148n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a149n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a150n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a151n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a152n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a153n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a154n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a155n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a156n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a157n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a158n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a159n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a160n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a161n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a162n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a163n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a164n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a165n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a166n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a167n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a168n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a169n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a170n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a171n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a172n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a173n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a174n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a175n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a176n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a177n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a178n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a179n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a180n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a181n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a182n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a183n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a184n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a185n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a186n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a187n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a188n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a189n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a190n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a191n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a192n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a193n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a194n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a195n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a196n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a197n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a198n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a199n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a200n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a201n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a202n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a203n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a204n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a205n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a206n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a207n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a208n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a209n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a250n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a211n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a212n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a213n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a214n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a215n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a216n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a217n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a218n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a219n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a220n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a221n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a222n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a223n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a224n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a225n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a226n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a227n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a228n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a229n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a230n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a231n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a232n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a233n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a234n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a235n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a236n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a237n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a238n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a239n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a240n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a241n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a242n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a243n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a244n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a245n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a246n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a247n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a248n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a249n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a250n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a251n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a252n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a253n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a254n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a255n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a256n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a257n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a258n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a259n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a260n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a261n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a262n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a263n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a264n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a265n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a266n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a267n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a268n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a269n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a270n"
        android:duration="5"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a271n"
        android:duration="5"/>
</animation-list>
```

Thanks for helping out

Comment: You've got to add a couple more details. What's `enim.xml` and why are you using Python in an XML file? What does `logcat` say? What's the specs of your handset vs the emulator you tested it on?

Comment: Post the stacktrace, or we will have 0% chance of helping you identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either you get an OutOfMemory Exceptions because so many Bitmaps in screen size must either be laoded separately or they crash when loaded at once. Also you could get an ANR if you do animation on Main UI Thread...